# How can I use template literals in an .env file?

Tags: javascript, jwt, environment-variables

I want to use JavaScript's Template Literals in an `.env` file.

Specifically, I am trying to store a JWT public key in the `.env` file:

```
PUBLIC_KEY=
`--BEGIN PUBLIC--
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
--END PUBLIC--`
```

But when I try to pull it out using `process.env.PUBLIC_KEY` JS returns an empty string.

I am using gulp to translate TypeScript but the `.env` is in the root directory and is `required` at the start of the `gulpfile`.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use template literals in an .env file. What you can do is store your key in a separate file and read it with `fs.readFile`.

Comment: Aren't `.env` files just plain text.
String templates are a JS feature. Not sure if  what you ask is possible,
If its a public key then can't it be exposed normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news. [v16.0.0](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1600-2022-02-02) and greater now supports JavaScript Template Literals.

You can use it like the following:

```
PUBLIC_KEY=`--BEGIN PUBLIC--
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
--END PUBLIC--`
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a bit of a workaround:

You can use `\n` to define the line breaks

So it looks like:

```
PUBLIC_KEY="AAA\nBBB\nCCC"
```

Tested it and its working